# Only show the advertisment that is closest to a random number

Tags: php, laravel

I got this where I want to display only one advertisement but randomly and it has more changes of displaying if the budget is higher. This is my code right now:

I already have the part where it calculates the percentage from 100% with alot of decimals but I'm lost in trying to display the advertisment with the percentage calculated and only show ONE advertisment.

If you have any questions or something like that, feel free to ask!

```php
@php

$advertisment = DB::table('advertisment')
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->get();

$totalbudget = 0;
$random = rand(100, 100000000000000);
$random1 = $random / 1000000000000;
echo $random1;
echo '<br><br>';


foreach ($advertisment as $ad) {
    $total = $totalbudget + $ad->budget;
    $totalbudget = $total;
}

// check what advertisment is the closest to the random number given

@endphp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand.  If all of your advertisements have a budget, and your `random1` represents a percent (1 - 100), you can try this in your existing function.  It will also still calculate the total you were looking for, just use the Laravel `sum()` function on the collection.  Note, I renamed the advertisement collection to plural for clarity.

```
$totalbudget = $advertisements->sum('budget');

$closest = null;
$closestAd = false
foreach ($advertisements as $ad) {
    // first get percentage of total for this budget:
    $thisPercent = ($ad->budget * 100) / $totalbudget;
    if ($closest === null || abs($random1 - $closest) > abs($thisPercent - $random1)) {
       $closest = $thisPercent;
       $colsestAd = $ad;
    }
}
```

At the end of the loop, you have both the percentage (`$closest`) and the ad itself (`$closestAd`) and the budget if you wish (`$closestAd->budget`).

There are a few unknowns, so this code may not work exactly.  Please use it as a guide and tweak to get it working for you.

Comment: It actually worked, but now I realize I don't want the closest but only the one that is above the percentage.

Comment: But could you actually help me with that?

Comment: Sure - just tweak it to add an extra if check in there.  IE Only set `$closest` if it is above `$random1`.  Easiest (though not totally efficient) would be to add another if check inside the one above.  `if($closest > $random1)` THEN set the new `$closest`.  However, you must also set some kind of check to make sure you actually have a value - `$closest` might be null because there *were* no `$ad->budget` (as a percent) above your desired %.

Comment: But how do you actually fix it so that the $ad->budget won't be null?

Comment: That's a different thing.  It's not ad->budget, but $closest and $closestAd that might not be set.  After the foreach loop, handle this with checks to see if one $closest isset and $closestAd is false.  If so, make code to show that there is no budget above the percent - IE just put a string in there to say that nothing matched (but handle the variables accordingly - don't pass a null back, or handle a null var on the blade page in favor of the string)

Comment: But now the id 1 gets never shown but the rest does. How would you solve this? Cause it doesn't matter but I want the id 1 advertisement still beeing shown cause he is actually paying for it :P. But btw, when I add alot more budget to it it does show id 1.

Comment: Well, that's a different condition than what you asked for before (you only wanted those above the %).  No problem though - just pull that advertisement that you want independent of ALL of the other stuff.  So, above the whole foreach thing, just do `$clientAd = $advertisements->where('id', $theIdYouWantToShow)` and send `$clientAd` through to the view :)